# How to stop Emacs from blinking?

Tags: echo-area, bell

My echo area blinks whenever I move the cursor up to end-of-buffer or beginning of buffer:

[image]

This happens even when I comment out everything in my `.emacs` file.  **Where does this feature come from and how do I remove it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have the variable `visible-bell` set to a non-`nil`
value (have a look at the manual node on [Beeping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Beeping.html) for more information).  Here's the docstring:

> Documentation:
>   Non-`nil` means try to flash the frame to represent a bell.
>
> See also `ring-bell-function`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You may also wish to set the `ring-bell-function`.  Here's its
docstring:

> Documentation:
>   Non-`nil` means call this function to ring the bell.
>   The function should accept no arguments.

Put the following in your init file, which should eliminate the
visible bell issues.  The first is *probably* sufficient, but you may wish to eliminate the bell entirely (I know I do), which is why the second part is in there.

```
(setq visible-bell       nil
      ring-bell-function #'ignore)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I want NO BELL, especially NO SOUND, but the flashing also annoys me. This is the one answer that actually worked - some were referring to older lisp commands emacs no longer accepted, others simply shifted the problem to he visual bell. I love emacs, but I wish they'd stop fooling around with this. Your answer should come up much higher in search :|